# Rails 4 Routes Params and Path Reversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, stripe-payments

My application environment is Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.8

And I'm trying to add Stripe checkout button on a listing page, as you may know, *Stripe's checkout doesn't require any interaction with your database so there isn't a Charges model. This also explains why the embedded ruby for the Stripe JS checkout from the example uses the form tag method instead of the form for method.*

So I just want to pass the listing id and save it by myself for reference. But there is something really weird in my Rails routes behavior:

routes.rb

```
# stripe
resources :charges
```

form tag in .haml

```
= form_tag charges_path(@listing.id) do
```

And no matter how I poked around, the Param and Path are always Reversed

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/111/charges">
```

How can I get below instead?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/charges/111">
```

Comment: Normally you would put a resource in a path helper instead of an id. Does that make a difference? So `charges_path(@listing)` instead of with `@listing.id`. Also why do you give a listing and not a charge as an argument to charges_path?

Comment: @Arjan thanks for your quick response. I tried charges_path(@listing), it's still reversed: `<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/111-name/charges">`

Comment: My goal is to add Stripe checkout button on a listing page, as you may know, _Stripe's checkout doesn't require any interaction with your database so there isn't a Charges model. This also explains why the embedded ruby for the Stripe JS checkout from the example uses the form tag method instead of the form for method._  So I just want to pass the listing id and save it by myself for reference.

Comment: What does listing look like?  You might need to do something like `charges_path(id: @listing.id)` if rails can't figure out the relationship.

Comment: @danielrsmith, thanks! your solution worked, `<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/en/charges?id=111-name">`

Comment: I'll add it as a solution so you can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your for path so that Rails knows what you are passing in.

```
form_tag charges_path(id: @listing.id)
```

Comment: thanks! your solution worked, <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/en/charges?id=111-name">

Comment: But why? Why I cant get correct way like /charges/111